# Netbeans Web Application

Tags: web, netbeans

I created a web application project in netbeans using the tomcat server. So I Always have to start the application from the IDE. Is it possible to do otherwise? To start it using the html page?

Answer (score 0):

If your application is running on the server you can call every page from the browser. But first you have to run your application from the IDE

Comment: But is it possible to not run it from the IDE?

Comment: I think you should do this using an external Tomcat server and not the Netbeans embedded. Check this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/tomcat-deploy-war) and tell me if it works